# Is it possible to attach to the Twitter streaming API with fiddler?

Tags: twitter, fiddler

Is it possible to attach to the Twitter streaming API with fiddler? Could someone tell me how to do it if it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter's streaming API runs over HTTP, and hence its traffic is caught with Fiddler. However, the traffic is "streamed" and thus you have to use Fiddler's **COMETPeek** to watch the in-process response.

1. Enable Streaming on the Fiddler toolbar.
2. Periodically right-click the stream's session and choose COMETPeek on the Session's context menu.

This will populate the response inspector with the traffic received from the server thus far.

Comment: wasted most of a day before the google foo kicked in enough to stumble onto this.  aaaar!   ;)